# Javascript regex grouping question

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to detect/pick apart strings like :

> tickets at entrance per person
>   ballons pp
>   tree planting

i.e. a description followed by an optional "pp" or "per person"

I try `(.+)\s+(per person|pp)` and that works; but the `pp|per person` suffix is then not optional.

I try `(.+)\s+(per person|pp)?` or `(.+)\s+(per person|pp){0,1}` to make it optional, but then I get "undefined for the second capture group". 
Curiously the first capture group contains the "per":

> matches: 0: (tickets at entrance per )
>   1: (tickets at entrance per)
>   2: (undefined)
>
> (tested via http://www.regextester.com/ online regex tester)

What am I doing wrong with that second capture group ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
^(.+?)\s*(per person|pp|)$
```

You can read it like this :

```
Starts with  
 (any characters but at least one and not in greedy mode)
 any space-characters
 ("per person" or "pp" or nothing)
end
```

Comment: Turns out this isn't quite what is needed after all. The required "any space character" in the middle there wont be present when the string does not contain the "pp|per person" suffix.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I had tried

^(.+)\s+(per person|pp|)$

which does work (note the \s+ vs the suggested \s*), but requires a trailing space if the per person|pp is not the suffix
So for example:
"tree planting"

will not be matched by this regex, although

"tree planting "

(note the trailing space) will be. The regex you suggested:

^(.+)\s*(per person|pp|)$

Does not work because the first group is greedy and returns the whole string, eg. 

"balloons per person"

returns 
1: (balloons per person)
2: ()

instead of what I want which is:
1: (balloons)
2: (per person)

Comment: Updated with an ungreedy "+" :)